# Looking for a full-time language school and/or a university in Paraguay

Tags: language, study, paraguay

I am hoping to visit Paraguay and study Spanish (and Guarani language in Paraguay which is particular to Paraguay) but there is no official "full time school" (or at least I have not found the relevant information yet). I have found information on a school called Idipar, but it's not full-time.

My scholarship agency would be happier to fund my language studies at a full-time school which has all the relevant paperwork (bureaucracy) and a student affairs section.

Also, are there any universities that offer courses in English so, one can get a feel of the academic environment? It helps the transition into Spanish/Guarani speaking mode too.

Answer (score 1):

You can take classes at  [La Universidad Autonoma de Asuncion](http://www.uaa.edu.py/relaciones_internacionales/estudiar_en_paraguay.php)

I also found these two classified adds:

[1](http://asuncionciudad.olx.com.py/ingles-espanol-personalizado-para-adultos-iid-66656960)

[2](http://clasipar.paraguay.com/ipeeg_instituto_de_espa_ol_a_extranjeros_563112.html)

I had better luck searching in Spanish instead of English. Try searching for

```
aprender español en paraguay
español para extranjeros en paraguay
escuela de idiomas en paraguay
```

if you have chrome, the browser will ask you if you want to auto-translate the page.